# Programmatically run Spring Boot in an existing embedded application server

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to run a Spring Boot applications programmatically in an existing, also programmatically created application server.

Running spring boot with it's embedded server is straightforward...

```
servletContext = SpringApplication.run(SomeApplication.class, args);
```

But in my case I need to do something like

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
// add handler, but how?
server.start()
```

I'm sure there's a fairly straightforward solution, but Google is not very helpful since all the results are about running spring with an embedded server.
Just to clarify. I don't want to package a jar/war file and run it. I want to programmatically start a Spring Boot application.

Comment: This can't be done.  Spring Boot uses an embedded Tomcat listener when you run as an executable JAR.  Everything they did depends on that.  You'll have to redo all of it to make Spring Boot work.  I would advise against this.

Comment: Interesting problem. But I think someone tried to solve it. Have a look here http://www.davidtanzer.net/running_multiple_spring_boot_apps_in_the_same_jvm not posting it as an answer as it's just a result of a google search :)